# Get item index from databound DevExpress CheckedListBoxControl

Tags: winforms, .net-2.0, devexpress, checkedlistbox

I am trying to find the index of a particular value from the [CheckedListBoxControl](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsCheckedListBoxControl_ctortopic). The CheckedListBoxControl has a DataSource, DisplayMember, ValueMember set to a DataTable and two columns receptively. Now I have to set the CheckedState Property to true by finding its index from CheckedListBoxControl by using some value from the ValueMember and then calling the [SetItemChecked()](http://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseCheckedListBoxControl_SetItemCheckedtopic.aspx) method with that index.

I'm not able to find any property or method which returns the index. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a list box control is bound to a data source, you can iterate throught all listbox items using the the [GetItem()](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseListBoxControl_GetItemtopic) method and the ItemCount property:

```
for(int i = 0; i < checkedListBoxControl.ItemCount; i++) {
    object dataRow = checkedListBoxControl.GetItem(i);
}
```

To find the index of the specified item you can use the [FindItem()](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseListBoxControl_FindItemtopic428) method
searching by DisplayText:

```
string s = "searchString";
int index = checkedListBoxControl.FindItem(startIndex, true, delegate(ListBoxFindItemArgs e) {
   e.IsFound = s.Equals(e.DisplayText);
});
```

searching by ValueMember:

```
object value = 100;
int index = checkedListBoxControl.FindItem(startIndex, true, delegate(ListBoxFindItemArgs e) {
   e.IsFound = object.Equals(value, e.ItemValue);
});
```

Please also take a look at the "[How to get checked rows of a data-bound CheckedListBoxControl](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E722)" article.

Comment: What if I only have the ValueMember values? I think and I know for sure that your second example won't work. Anyway thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Soham Dasgupta: I exactly know that second sample works as expected to me. Anyway I have updated my second sample for searching by ValueMember also.

Comment: This syntax does not seem to work. Please check if I'm wrong. I'm using VB.Net, VS2008, Framework Version: 2.0 - `checkedListBoxControl.FindItem(0, True, Function(e As ListBoxFindItemArgs) e.IsFound = Object.Equals(Value, e.ItemValue))`

Comment: @Soham Dasgupta: BTW I'm using C# in my samples

Comment: I'm just unable to understand as to why this is not working. Can you help. I think this is the only way you write inline lambda functions in VB.NET 9.0 right?

Comment: In VB it looks like this:
`CheckedListBoxControl1.FindItem(0, True, Sub(e As ListBoxFindItemArgs) e.IsFound = Object.Equals(value, e.ItemValue))`

Comment: `Sub` keyword is not applicable in this context. It is producing an error - `Expression expected.`

Comment: VB, .Net 2.0, VS2008:
`CheckedListBoxControl1.FindItem(0, True, AddressOf Filter)
    
Sub Filter(ByVal e As ListBoxFindItemArgs)
    Dim value As Integer = 200
    e.IsFound = Object.Equals(value, e.ItemValue)
End Sub`

Comment: Thanks. I've worked that out. Anyway I just hoped there were some CSharp type short method for doing so. Anyway Thanks.