# VB.NET inline delegate predicate not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, delegates, .net-2.0, predicate

This is my problem. If I write this -

```
Private ListValue As Object = Nothing

Private Sub FindIndex(ByVal e As ListBoxFindItemArgs)
    e.IsFound = Object.Equals(ListValue, e.ItemValue)
End Sub

Private Sub SearchValues
    ListValue  = 5
    Index = Me.lst_department.FindItem(0, True, AddressOf FindIndex)
End Sub
```

But I'm just out of my wit why this code, written to do the same thing is not working -

```
Private Sub SearchValues
    ListValue  = 5
    Index = Me.lst_department.FindItem(0, True, Function(e As ListBoxFindItemArgs) e.IsFound = Object.Equals(ListValue, e.ItemValue))
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the type of lst_department? And what *exactly* is happening? ("not working" doesn't tell us much).

Comment: @JonSkeet lst_department is a type of `DevExpress.XtraEditors.CheckedListBoxControl`. What I'm trying to achieve is mentioned in this question which I asked - [Get item index from databound DevExpress CheckedListBoxControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003193/get-item-index-from-databound-devexpress-checkedlistboxcontrol).

Comment: It would have been useful to have given both of those bits of information - as well as the signature of `FindItem` - in the original question. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for suggestions for your next question.

Comment: @JonSkeet That was some good insight. Thanks. Opened my eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your “predicate” is *not* a function<sup>1</sup>, it’s a `Sub`. If you are using the most recent version of VB, you can write the following; otherwise, you’re out of luck:

```
Index = Me.lst_department.FindItem(0, True, Sub(e As ListBoxFindItemArgs) e.IsFound = Object.Equals(ListValue, e.ItemValue))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Furthermore, it’s not a predicate. A predicate is a specific type of function having the signature `Function(x As T) As Boolean` for some type `T`.

Comment: If I write `Sub` then the compiler is generating an error - `Expression expected.` Is there any other way?

Comment: @Sohan Apparently you don’t have the most recent version of VB (VB10). No, there is no other way since this feature didn’t exist before.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Appreciate it.