# Use CheckBoxList in DevExpress vb.net Assign & Evaluate?

Tags: c, vb.net, visual-studio, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Hello my code example is :

/*
bdEmpresa (BindingSource) 
Contains:

selet idEmpresa,Nombre,Acceso from Empresa

Result

1, Empresa1,true

2, Empresa2,false

3, Empresa2,true

*/

clEmpresas.DataSource = bdEmpresa

clEmpresas.DisplayMember = ? (Nombre)

clEmpresas.ValueMember = ? (Acceso)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code we would use

```
        With clEmpresas.Properties
            If .DataSource IsNot Nothing Then .DataSource = Nothing
            .DataSource =  bdEmpresa 
            If .DataSource.rows.count = 0 Then Return Nothing 'no data to load
            'get the names from the dataset, don't expect them to be specific names
            .ValueMember = .DataSource.rows(0).Table.Columns(0).ColumnName
            .DisplayMember = .DataSource.rows(0).Table.Columns(1).ColumnName

            'Set the selected items, comma separated list of ids
            If selectedIds <> "" Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To .ItemCount - 1
                    If Array.IndexOf(selectedIds.Split(","), .GetItemValue(i).ToString) >= 0 Then
                        .SetItemChecked(i, True)
                    End If
                Next
            End If

        End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CheckMember](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.CheckedListBoxControl.members) property to let the control automatically check the selection values from your assigned data source:
e.g.

```
clEmpresas.DataSource = bdEmpresa
clEmpresas.DisplayMember = "Nombre"
clEmpresas.ValueMember = "idEmpresa"
clEmpresas.CheckMember= "Acceso"
```

After that you can use the [CheckedItems](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.BaseCheckedListBoxControl.CheckedItems.property) property to get the selected items if user changes selection in the control. see below example:

```
Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click
        For Each item As DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CheckedListBoxItem In CheckedListBoxControl1.CheckedItems
            MessageBox.Show(item.Value.ToString())
        Next
    End Sub
```

Refer these:
[get the selected items from a checkedlistbox](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q219009/get-the-selected-items-from-a-checkedlistbox)
[How to get checked rows of a data-bound CheckedListBoxControl](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E722/how-to-get-checked-rows-of-a-data-bound-checkedlistboxcontrol)
[Get item index from databound DevExpress CheckedListBoxControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003193/get-item-index-from-databound-devexpress-checkedlistboxcontrol)